# Update Weight in magento 1.9 on mass

Tags: database, magento

I am trying to create a MySQL statement that I can put in a php script to update the weight on a few thousand products in magento 1.9.

This is the statement I currently have:

```
UPDATE dp_catalog_product_entity_decimal AS ped JOIN dp_eav_attribute AS ea ON  ea.entity_type_id = 10 AND ea.attribute_code = 'weight' AND ped.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id SET ped.value = 8 WHERE ped.entity_id = P1000X3;
```

It was partially taken from another post so I am not sure if it will work at all but I currently have the error "#1054 - Unknown column 'P1000X3' in 'where clause'"

I am not that great with sql joins and I dont really know the magento databse at all so any help to get this statement to work is much apreciated.

Thanks.
Matt

Comment: If you want to change the weight on a few thousand products, you should look for a solution with one query first instead of one per product (if that's possible). Otherwise you gain nothing with plain SQL and should better use the Magento models. What are the rules by which you need to update?

Comment: I basically have a spreadsheet with a list of SKU's and a list of weights and I just need to get all the right weights on the right items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct SQL to update the weight of a product with a specific SKU in Magento is this (replace `YOUR-MAGENTO-SKU` with the sku of the item you want to update, and the `8` with the weight value).

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_decimal AS cped
JOIN eav_attribute AS ea ON ea.entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity AS cpe ON cpe.entity_id = cped.entity_id
AND ea.attribute_code = 'weight'
AND cped.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id
SET cped.value = 8
WHERE cpe.sku = 'YOUR-MAGENTO-SKU';
```

In your case, you have the table prefix `dp_`, and the product sku `P1000X3`, so the correct SQL for you would be:

```
UPDATE dp_catalog_product_entity_decimal AS cped
JOIN dp_eav_attribute AS ea ON ea.entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM dp_eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')
LEFT JOIN dp_catalog_product_entity AS cpe ON cpe.entity_id = cped.entity_id
AND ea.attribute_code = 'weight'
AND cped.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id
SET cped.value = 8
WHERE cpe.sku = 'P1000X3';
```

After running this, be sure to reindex your Magento Indexes.

Comment: Thank you very much that worked perfect, 

Cheers, Matt

Comment: This ended up changing special price and MSRP price.

Answer (score 1):

Do your Magento tables have the prefix `dp_`?  Make sure of this.

Also on this part:

```
WHERE ped.entity_id = P1000X3;
```

**ped.entity_id** will be an integer value (number).

I'm not sure where you got `P1000X3`, but using that won't work (it's a string value).  Even so, strings should be wrapped with a single quotes `'`, like this:

```
'P1000X3';
```

Comment: Yes they have the dp_ prefex. The P1000X3 is the SKU is there a way to search so it is WHERE ped.entity_sku or something?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I was searching around the internet and found this `SELECT cped.VALUE, cpe.sku, UPDATE.*
FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal cped
INNER JOIN eav_attribute ea ON ea.attribute_id = cped.attribute_id AND ea.attribute_code = 'weight'
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity cpe ON cpe.entity_id = cped.entity_id
INNER JOIN _product_weight_updates UPDATE ON UPDATE.sku = cpe.sku
LIMIT 20
`
It works on magento 1.7 but I do not really know how to make it work with my database, I have created a table and such. Thanks

Comment: I've added another answer with the correct SQL for updating a product's weight that has a specific sku value.